# TFTP Server on 10.6.6

Tags: macos, network

How do I enable an existing TFTPd within 10.6.6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to run it with any special settings?  By default, it runs chrooted in /private/tftpboot; if you want anything different in the setup, edit /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist as appropriate.  Then, activate it with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist
```

Comment: May need to sudo that.

Comment: @Spiff: D'oh!  Fixed.

Comment: default's is fine.. my only problem is

mbp:~ alexus$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist
bind(): Address already in use
com.apple.tftpd: Already loaded
mbp:~ alexus$

Comment: It sounds like it's already activated.  Try `sudo launchctl list com.apple.tftpd` and see if it gives you a differently-formatted dum of the .plist (if it's loaded), or an error message (if it's not loaded).  Also, try `sudo lsof -i:tftp` and see if it shows launchd listening on the tftp port (note that launchd will start tftp when it sees incoming traffic on the tftp port).